# Как отложить выполнение задания quartz?

Tags: java, quartz

Сейчас в моём приложении задания запускаются на выполнение сразу же, c помощью `makeImmediateTrigger`:

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");
sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
sched.start();
String jobName = generateJobDetailName();
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(jobName, GRP_Immediate, MyJob.class);
jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(MyJob.DATA, data);
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0, 0);
trigger.setName(jobName + "_Simpletrigger");
sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Я хочу изменить приложение так, чтобы одновременно выполнялось не более пяти заданий, остальные становились в очередь и запускались только после того, как какие-либо из работающих пяти потоков освободятся. Как лучше это сделать? Я предполагаю, что это можно сделать как-то так:

```
if (sched.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().size() <= 5) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

но что тогда нужно писать в блоке `else`?